# Show / hide div button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a show / hide menu button using jQuery.

The menu is contained in a div, and I am trying to setup a button to show and hide it. Here's my code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div id="items">
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>about</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <p class="dismiss-btn" id="btn-hide"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    //DOM loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Hide the top info bar
        $('#btn-hide').click(function(){
            $("#items").toggle("slow"); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I click the button, it hides the content, and then it shows it again... Any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/F2tE5/1/

Comment: Works all good [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/rPVwY/)

Comment: Maybe a jquery version or browser thing?

Comment: Can you bundle up a fiddle, maybe post the css too? Are you refreshing the page in any way (programatically)?

Comment: Are you double-clicking?

Comment: NOo way, I'm just checking on the fiddle and it seems to be working. It may interfere with some other scripts I guess.. I also have loaded jQuery UI. I've tried to disable taht with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me but one thing you could try:

```
$('#btn-hide').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $("#items").toggle("slow"); 
});
```

This will stop any other "clicks" on that element or parent elements.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thanks for the info link as well!